# Bootstrap grid system, a column being too long

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm writing some front for my application, and I realized that there is a gap  between the previous row and the next row because one of the grid elements is too long, after trying to nest rows I still couldn't get it to work. Heres an example of what it looks like:

https://jsfiddle.net/kkotwal94/f6d9dp98/embedded/result/

```
<div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                 <h1 class="page-header">
                            Profile <small>My Info</small>
                        </h1>

                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="active"> <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> 
                        <Link to="/dashboard/main">Dashboard</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>Profile</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">{firstName + " " + lastName}&#39;s Profile</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"First Name: " + firstName}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"Last Name: " + lastName}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"Section: " + section}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"Gender: " + gender}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"Location: " + location}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Current Profile</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">{firstName + " " + lastName}&#39;s Profile Changes</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form action="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                                <input type="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder={firstName} ref="firstName" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                                <input type="lastName" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder={lastName} ref="lastName" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="section">Section</label>
                                <input type="section" class="form-control" id="section" placeholder={section} ref="section" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="gender">Gender</label>
                                <input type="gender" class="form-control" id="gender" placeholder={gender} ref="gender" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="location">Location</label>
                                <input type="location" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder={location} ref="location" />
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-default" onClick={this._onProfileUpdate}>Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Update Info</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">{firstName + " " + lastName}&#39;s Profile</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"First Name: " + firstName}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"Last Name: " + lastName}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"Section: " + section}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"Gender: " + gender}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"Location: " + location}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Current Profile</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the code is here : http://jsfiddle.net/kkotwal94/f6d9dp98/

I would like for it to look like :

```
----------
div1 div2
div3   |
       |
---------
```

instead of

```
----------
div1 div2
       |
       |
div3
---------
```

Comment: Ok, so either the div3, or the cols are clearing one another, which is what you dont want.  So lets see. Its hard to tell what you want since you dont have any concrete class names there , instead div1, div2, etc..  

What i need to know is, what responsive size are you viewing it in?  lg, md, sm, or what?  If you go full screen, so you still see the problem?  What i see is the bad wrap when you go to the lg size only.

Comment: Could you put div 1 and div 3 in the same row/column. Or if it goes into Mobile is it important that div 2 be in the middle?

Comment: Putting it in the same row, creates the same effect

Comment: So you must remember they MUST add up to 12, what does 7+4 =?  If you want a col7, make sure you have a col5 blank, if you want a col 7, and a col4, make sure you also have a col1 blank.  make sense?  Your rules are ONLY taking effect at the largest size, and only the rows are taking effect at md and smaller, this is your problem.  Ill give you an example.

Comment: @BrianThomas: You dont have to add them up to 12, all 7+4 does is leave a 1 to the right. It is not causing the problem described.

Comment: See here https://jsfiddle.net/f6d9dp98/4/  does that help?  They dont have to add up to 12? What do you mean?  I know they atleast represent a 12th.

Comment: @BrianThomas: I mean 12 = 100%, but you are not always looking to utilize 100% width

Comment: right, but your looking to fit for it, so that when its reduced, its in a percentage.  But yes you can leave the last col-lg-1 out if you want, as long as you see that its still represented when in actual `lg` mode.  its better to code it empty, so you have a clear pic of whats going on IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build your main content structure in columns, not rows. Div 1 and 3 in the same column, div 2 in another.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                 <h1 class="page-header">
                            Profile <small>My Info</small>
                        </h1>

                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="active"> <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> 
                        <Link to="/dashboard/main">Dashboard</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>Profile</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">{firstName + " " + lastName}&#39;s Profile</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"First Name: " + firstName}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"Last Name: " + lastName}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"Section: " + section}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"Gender: " + gender}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"Location: " + location}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Current Profile</div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">{firstName + " " + lastName}&#39;s Profile</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"First Name: " + firstName}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"Last Name: " + lastName}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"Section: " + section}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"Gender: " + gender}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{"Location: " + location}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Current Profile</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">{firstName + " " + lastName}&#39;s Profile Changes</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form action="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                                <input type="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder={firstName} ref="firstName" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                                <input type="lastName" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder={lastName} ref="lastName" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="section">Section</label>
                                <input type="section" class="form-control" id="section" placeholder={section} ref="section" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="gender">Gender</label>
                                <input type="gender" class="form-control" id="gender" placeholder={gender} ref="gender" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="location">Location</label>
                                <input type="location" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder={location} ref="location" />
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-default" onClick={this._onProfileUpdate}>Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">Update Info</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is proper implementation and everything, just what I was looking for and missed out on in the documentation some how.

Comment: Your welcome :) The fun starts when you want to prioritize them for mobile, then you have to reorder them first, then use push/pull offset to get it the pre-reorderd way, and then it will fall back nicely on mobile. But thats a lesson for another day. :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The cols need to add up to 12, or atleast they represent a 12th.  If you dont accommodate the space, there will be wrapping issues.  Try to use styles instead of CSS adjustments.

http://jsfiddle.net/fn7b5fcu/4/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h1 class="page-header">
        Profile <small>My Info</small>
      </h1>

      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="active"> <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
          <Link to="/dashboard/main">Dashboard</Link>
        </li>
        <li>Profile</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">{firstName + " " + lastName}&#39;s Profile</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">{"First Name: " + firstName}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Current Profile</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">{firstName + " " + lastName}&#39;s Profile Changes</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <form action="">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
              <input type="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder={firstName} ref="firstName" />
              <button class="btn btn-default" onClick={this._onProfileUpdate}>Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Update Info</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">{firstName + " " + lastName}&#39;s Profile</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">{"First Name: " + firstName}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Current Profile</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So in my experience, this is proper use of bootstrap.  The goal is to use styles to make your adjustments, which keeps you from adding over-rides to a bare minimal.  You only want to override styles when you have to.  The idea of the grid is to use bootstrap styles to achieve results, the col numbers are there for a reason, this is how you indicate your structure, via css styles.

He is using col-lg, im showing him how to properly use col-lg.  :-)

And yes @turbopipp is absolutely correct, you need to separate the two cols(fixed the tags), nice going, thanks ;-)

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution should just be to set div2 to float right:

```
#div2 {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: You call that simple, tweaking the css?  That can cause later problems, huge headaches if you don't know what your doing, and is not properly leveraging the Grid, therefore much less than simple IMO.  Remember the Grid was the topic of concern here.