# Bootstrap grid: vertical alignment issue in columns

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

I am using Bootstrap's grid system in the footer of the website I'm currently developing.

I want to have 2 columns next to each other (so I'm using the class col-6 for each one of them), but since some elements are too large, the text wraps to a second line and the column grows vertically to have enough place for them.
This makes the other column grow vertically too and puts a space between it and the next element.

[What is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGQEA.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJOpS.png)

I've seen a similar problem which was resolved but the solution was to put an element from the right column and the next row's element from the left column in a same row, which solves the problem but it is not a viable option when I'm dealing with quite a number of entries.

[Mentioned post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335667/bootstrap-grid-system-a-column-being-too-long)

Here's my HTML for these elements :

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-12">
<p class="footer-title">NOS SOCIÉTÉS</p>
<div class="row no-gutters">

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"><p><a href="#">Holding Stihlé Frères (Siège)</a><span> - Turckheim</span></p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"><p><a href="#">Stihlé SAV Centre</a><span> - Logelbach</span></p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"><p><a href="#">Stihlé Frères 68</a><span> - Wihr-au-Val</span></p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"><p><a href="#">Stihlé SAV Sud</a><span> - Sausheim</span></p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"><p><a href="#">Jaenicke</a><span> - Guebwiller</span></p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"><p><a href="#">Stihlé SAV Nord</a><span> - Illkirch-Graffenstaden</span></p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"><p><a href="#">René Graf</a><span> - Colmar</span></p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"><p><a href="#">Stihlé Accessibilité</a><span> - Turckheim</span></p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"><p><a href="#">Graf Services Plus</a><span> - Colmar</span></p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"><p><a href="#">Alsace Home Service</a><span> - Colmar / Sausheim / Vieux-Thann / Illkirch-Graffenstaden</span></p></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"><p><a href="#">Philippe</a><span> - Sainte-Marie-aux-Mines</span></p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"><p><a href="#">Vivale</a><span> - Turckheim</span></p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"><p><a href="#">Stihlé Sud Alsace</a><span> - Hésingue</span></p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"><p><a href="#">Stihlé Frères 67</a><span> - Illkirch-Graffenstaden</span></p></div>

</div>
```

If you need any other information, feel free to ask, I might have forgotten something useful.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I have two questions 1: why is it not possible to use just 2 columns? If we understand the reason for what you want to do, it can help us to give you a solution that is suitable. 2: Can you control the order that the items appear in, e.g. will they always be output in this order (i.e. column1, column2, column1, column2) or can you change that?

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering ! I haven't shown it nor talked about it but these two columns are not the only ones in my footer. I have 4 columns and the one I talked about in the post is the second one. Within this column, I create an other row and make 2 other columns by putting col-6 as you can see. I can't put the entire code of the 4 columns here but if you need it I'll make a reply to my post with it in. For your second question, no, the only way I can change the order would be to rearrange my HTML by myself

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other way to display items from left to right to look like the image if they have different heights unless you're going to go for a more complicated solution like masonry.js. I can give you an answer that would achieve the look you want, but they would be in a different order - it would change from col1, col2, col1, col2 to col1, col1, col1, until half way and then col2, col2 etc. If you need them in a different order you would need to rearrange the HTML. Is that any good?

Comment: I was told to use the least amount of external resources possible so I doubt using masonry.js would be ok for my tutor here but I'll be sure to keep it in mind for my next project :)

On another hand, I'd love to see your solution rearranging the order, I have no restriction on that part so if that works then it'd be perfect.

Comment: OK, I'll post an answer with this later... have some work of my own to do right now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order of the HTML items can be changed (which you can do), then there are 2 ways to do this.

**1. Use 2 columns instead of multiple columns**

Create 2 columns and put half of the items in the first column and half in the second. This is how the answer you linked to does it and you said you couldn't do that, but it is the only way if you want to use the grid.

***Run the snippet to see it in action:*** (Note: I have changed 'col-sm-12' to `col-sm-6` just so that you can see the effect when you run the snippet)

```css
.row.no-gutters p { background:#eee; }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p class="footer-title">NOS SOCIÉTÉS</p>
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
        <p><a href="#">Holding Stihlé Frères (Siège)</a><span> - Turckheim</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Stihlé SAV Centre</a><span> - Logelbach</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Stihlé Frères 68</a><span> - Wihr-au-Val</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Stihlé SAV Sud</a><span> - Sausheim</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Jaenicke</a><span> - Guebwiller</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Stihlé SAV Nord</a><span> - Illkirch-Graffenstaden</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">René Graf</a><span> - Colmar</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
        <p><a href="#">Stihlé Accessibilité</a><span> - Turckheim</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Graf Services Plus</a><span> - Colmar</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Alsace Home Service</a><span> - Colmar / Sausheim / Vieux-Thann / Illkirch-Graffenstaden</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Philippe</a><span> - Sainte-Marie-aux-Mines</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Vivale</a><span> - Turckheim</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Stihlé Sud Alsace</a><span> - Hésingue</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Stihlé Frères 67</a><span> - Illkirch-Graffenstaden</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**2. Use CSS columns.**

Put all of your items in one single `div`, and add the following CSS to the class for that div.

This CSS will display the content in the number of columns in `column-count` (i.e. 2 here):

```
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-moz-column-count: 2;
column-count: 2;
```

This sets the gap between the columns - you were using no-gutter so I've set it to 0 here.

```
-webkit-column-gap: 0;
-moz-column-gap: 0;
 column-gap: 0;
```

Finally, this sets the minimum width for the columns. Here we've set it to 200.

```
-webkit-column-width: 200px;
-moz-column-width: 200px;
column-width: 200px;
```

This will create 2 columns while the container is at least 400px (i.e. 2 cols x 200px). If the container gets smaller than 400px, it can no longer fit 2 columns so it will display everything in a single column.

***Run the snippet to see it in action:***

```css
/* Just for the demo */
.mycolumns p {background:#eee;}
.mycolumns {
    /* specify number of columns */
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;

    /* specify min width for columns */
    -webkit-column-width: 200px;
    -moz-column-width: 200px;
    column-width: 200px;

    /* specify the gap between columns */
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 0;
     column-gap: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <p class="footer-title">NOS SOCIÉTÉS</p>
    <div class="mycolumns">
        <p><a href="#">Holding Stihlé Frères (Siège)</a><span> - Turckheim</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Stihlé SAV Centre</a><span> - Logelbach</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Stihlé Frères 68</a><span> - Wihr-au-Val</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Stihlé SAV Sud</a><span> - Sausheim</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Jaenicke</a><span> - Guebwiller</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Stihlé SAV Nord</a><span> - Illkirch-Graffenstaden</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">René Graf</a><span> - Colmar</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Stihlé Accessibilité</a><span> - Turckheim</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Graf Services Plus</a><span> - Colmar</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Alsace Home Service</a><span> - Colmar / Sausheim / Vieux-Thann / Illkirch-Graffenstaden</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Philippe</a><span> - Sainte-Marie-aux-Mines</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Vivale</a><span> - Turckheim</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Stihlé Sud Alsace</a><span> - Hésingue</span></p>
        <p><a href="#">Stihlé Frères 67</a><span> - Illkirch-Graffenstaden</span></p>
    </div>
```

**Note that you will need to change the order of the items to suit, no matter how you do this.**

Displaying them "across and down" (i.e. col 1, col 2, col 1, col 2 etc) with variable height items can't easily be achieved without getting the gap you are experiencing. They have to be displayed "down and across" (i.e. fill column 1 first, then column 2) to overcome the gapping.

Comment: Hi again, thank you very much for this detailed answer. Right now I can't test your solutions in real conditions but I'll test them tomorrow. I have been stuck on this problem almost since the start of the project so I'm really glad you could help me out. Once I tried I'll let you know how it wnet :)

Comment: Hey, I wanted to let you know that I now have the visual I wanted, huge thanks ! I used the first solution